# Need help setting up MongoDB on Goorm.io Workspace (running a MacBook)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I've been working through an online course on Udemy and have reached a wall in my progress. I currently have to set up MongoDB inside GoormIDE so that I can keep it running whilst I build more of my project (I need to interact with it inside this platform). I have managed to get it running on my terminal on the MacBook but this is of little use when I am trying to get it to run inside the Goorm.io terminal. Has anyone met with this problem before? I feel specifically hindered by Mac OS but I want to get past it.

Have tried following installation videos (once successfully installing to MacBook terminal but want to install in Goorm.io terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Open your GoormIDE Container and within the container open a terminal.  In the terminal window enter this command:

```
apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 9DA31620334BD75D9DCB49F368818C72E52529D4 && (echo "deb [ arch=amd64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.0 multiverse" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.0.list) && apt-get update && apt-get install -y mongodb-org && mkdir -p /data/db
```

when mongodb is done installing enter in the terminal:

```
mongod
```

in order to start the mongodb server.
then in goormide go to Window->New Terminal Window.
this will open a new terminal on top of the current one.  In the new terminal type

```
mongo
```

it will start the database and you'll see the cursor changing to >.  you can run

```
show dbs
```

to see your databases...

​Source: https://help.goorm.io/en/goormide/18.faq/language-and-environment/how-to-install-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix the issue! I have been using Goorm.IDE with a course called the Web Developer Bootcamp on Udemy. I managed to practice and set up MongoDB outside GoormIDE and in my inexperience thought that it would somehow be accessible on Goorm.IDE. Not the case. I subsequently discovered that the relevant MongoDB package for Goorm IDE was not available and so I could not install it successfully within the site. *It may not be your own efforts but the editor you are using.* I have since migrated my project to Codeanywhere.com and it has proved more user friendly, faster, and up-to-date. I have managed to resume my project and run MongoDB successfuly simply by using the Ubuntu installation manual on their website.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah! Same here...
This is the solution after probing;
Make use of this links sequentially:: 
{echo "deb [ arch=amd64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/4.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.0.list}
{echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/4.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.0.list}

Copy it from the brackets and past it on your goorm terminal. It worked for me and I believe it will work for you too. Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this problem as well. Instead of typing ./mongod just type mongod in the terminal. Then type mongo in the secondary terminal. Hope this helps!